# Store array of arrays in array

Tags: arduino

It is possible store bitmap in array in Wiring programing language (Arduino)?

```
boolean triangleMap[DISPLAY_HEIGHT][DISPLAY_WIDTH] = {
{0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}
};

boolean squareMap[DISPLAY_HEIGHT][DISPLAY_WIDTH] = {
{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}
};

boolean symbols[] = {triangleMap, squareMap};
```

**??? symbols[]** = {triangleMap, squareMap};

> error: invalid conversion from ‘boolean (*)[8] {aka unsigned char
>   (*)[8]}’ to ‘boolean {aka unsigned char}’ [-fpermissive]

I do not know whether it is possible to store *triangleMap* and *squareMap* bitmap in *symbols* array?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are already using multidimensional arrays, why not a three dimensional array to combine them both... `bool symbols[SYMBOL_COUNT][DISPLAY_HEIGHT][DISPLAY_WIDTH] = {};`

Comment: Also, note that boolean arrays in embedded program can be horribly inefficient. Much better to use integers as bit arrays if possible (if you stick with 8x8 arrays, you can use chars/uint8_t).

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the correct type.

`boolean symbols[]` means "I want an array of booleans", while what you want is "an array of booleans MATRICES. So this

```
boolean symbols[][DISPLAY_HEIGHT][DISPLAY_WIDTH] = {triangleMap, squareMap};
```

should work

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this does not work:

> byte symbols[][DISPLAY_HEIGHT][DISPLAY_WIDTH] = {triangleMap,
>   squareMap};

But, this work:

```
byte symbols[][DISPLAY_HEIGHT][DISPLAY_WIDTH] ={  
        { //triangle
          {0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0},
          {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
          {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
          {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
          {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
          {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
          {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
          {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}
        },
        {//square
          {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
          {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
          {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
          {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
          {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
          {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
          {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
          {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}
      },
      {//cycle
          {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
          {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
          {0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0},
          {0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0},
          {0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0},
          {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
          {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
          {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
      }    
  };
```

Thanks a lot.